# run Test Suite in MTM

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-test-manager

I have many test case in Microsoft test manager that works right. I must run them single.I want run a test suite that contains many Test case. but When I select a test suite the run Option is disable.
How I can run a test suite or a test plan.
Sincerely you M.bagheri

Answer (score 3):

If you create a test suite with test cases inside, then you can go under the tab "Test" in MTM right click on the test suite and you can "Run" or "Run with Options". If that is not available something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because you have not selected any test in right side panel of MTM. Select all/intended test cases from the tests available in your test suite and then click on run option, you will see the option enabled:

Since you mentioned that you want to run test in your test suite, i assume that you have targeted tests available in your test suite:

**Alternate Approch:**

You can use **tcm.exe** command line utility to run test cases: (Open visual studio command prompt and run following sample command from your

***tcm run /create /title:""  /planid: /suiteid: /configid: /settingsname:"" /testenvironment:"" /collection:http://:8080/tfs /teamproject: /include***

You can go through following link for more info on using tcm utility:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465192.aspx

Following commands might come in handy for finding values for options in above mentioned tcm command:

***tcm plans /list /collection:http://[your_tfs_server_name]:8080/tfs /teamproject:[your_tfsproject_name]***

***tcm configs /list /collection:http://[your_tfs_server_name]:8080/tfs /teamproject:[your_tfsproject_name]***

***tcm suites /list /planid:[your_testplan_id_can_be_picked_from_first_command] /collection:http://[your_tfs_server_name]:8080/tfs /teamproject:[your_tfsproject_name]***

***tcm help***